# How to find the end of node in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I want to insert a text after the end of next closing tag in tinymce. For ex. `<p>This is <span>This is a s|pan</span>paragraph</p>`. '|' shows my cursor position, I need to place my cursor after `'</span>|'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an outline for what you need to do:

```
// get a reference to the Editor instance
// (depending on your scenario, this may come from a different place)
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

// get the node your cursor is in - the one you want to insert after
var endNode = editor.selection.getEnd();

// move the selection after the current node
editor.selection.select(endNode).collapse(false);

// insert your content
editor.selection.setContent("abc");
```

You can use [the API docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/) to actually make it work. What I wrote above is based strictly on the docs - as I don't have the time now to test it -, so it probably won't be plug and play.

Comment: Thanks @Alin Purcaru... A minor change in the third line. `editor.selection.collapse();` worked for me.

Comment: yea, the 3rd line should actually be two lines:

    `editor.selection.select(endNode); editor.selection.collapse(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the previous answer and comments into one block of code...

```
// Get a reference to the Editor instance
// (depending on your scenario, this may come from a different place)
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

// get the node your cursor is in - the one you want to insert after
var endNode = editor.selection.getEnd();

// move the selection after the current node
editor.selection.select(endNode);
editor.selection.collapse(false);

// insert your content
editor.selection.setContent("abc");
```